# SSRS: Static Rows and Columns

Tags: reporting-services

I am new to SSRS and Stuck in a situation where I need to display the Data.
I want to show data with static rows and columns as shown below

[image]
Is there a way I can set the static rows and columns in the ssrs.

Comment: Do you only have 8 columns and 8 rows that are fixed? And you just need the data to go in the correct slots, the rest that don't have data being empty?

Comment: Your question could use more detail. Could you add a sample data set (and/or query) and share how that should be placed in the grid? Or if you just want one cell of the grid populated, indicate that as well. (So no repeating of pages or sections?) You can certainly set a fixed grid of 8 rows and columns in SSRS...

Comment: @user3992 yes, my rows and columns are fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a regular tablix connected to your data source

[image]

Then you can add as many columns as required
[image]

In the end it can look like this with a better coloring/font etc.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to create a query which returns 64 rows and 3 columns:

Column A : "Row 1", "Row 2"...."Row 8"

Column B : "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column3" ..."Column 8"

Column C : Data

Then Create a Matrix, with A in Row and B in Column and C in Data.

Basically, Column A and Column B will be a shell which holds the data, then left join with the data to form your full data set.